# Pass bash variables into subprocess arguments

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

In a bash shell script I would like to do the following:

```
for file in /path/to/original/*
  nfcapd -p 12345 -l /path/to/new/file/ -x 'mv %d%f %d/$file'
done
```

So nfcapd -x lets you add a command to execute on completion. I want to mv %d%f (move directorypath/defaultfilename) to %d/$file (directorypath/original_file_name). Unfortunately, this is saving the new file as "$file" not the value of the $file variable. Is there a way to escape the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes around the argument to -x, it will be:

```
nfcapd -p 12345 -l /path/to/new/file/ -x "mv %d%f %d/$file"
```

Shell variables are not expanded inside single quotes.